# Find the row with the next closest rating (score) for each row in a table

Tags: sql, ms-access, detect, similarity

I am an amateur user of SQL and I want to construct a quite advances SQL query for detecting the most similar object within a database in Access

More precisely my database has the following strucure

```
                        FID     PC1       PC2      PC3        PC4
                         1      0.765     0.043    -0.0023    -0.0009
                         5      0.223     -0.09    -0.0045    -0.0002  
                        300
                        ...
                        ...
                        ...
```

In this structure I would like detect per object (FID) which other (FID) is most similar to this one by considering all 4 PC attributes values (PC1,PC2,PC3,PC4).

I can think a mathematical solution for this problem but I am not sure how to implement it in an SQL query. Can somebody advice me on this ?

Thanks in advance

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

The exact query that I am running looks like this:

---

```
 SELECT 
     Merged_Info.TARGET_FID, 
     Merged_Info.PC1_MEAN, 
     Merged_Info.PC2_Mean, 
     Merged_Info.PC3_MEAN, 
     Merged_Info.PC4_MEAN, 
     ([PC1_MEAN]+0.7*[PC2_Mean]+0.4*[PC3_MEAN]+0.2*[PC4_MEAN])/4 AS Rating
 FROM Merged_Info


SELECT
  q1.TARGET_FID,
  (
      SELECT TOP 1 q2.TARGET_FID 
      FROM myRatings  AS q2 
      WHERE q2.TARGET_FID<>q1.TARGET_FID 
      ORDER BY Abs(q2.Rating-q1.Rating), q2.TARGET_FID
  ) AS Closest_TARGET_FID
FROM myRatings  AS q1
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your exact SQL queries into Access 2010 and they worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have sample data in a table named [myData]:

```
FID  PC1  PC2  PC3  PC4
---  ---  ---  ---  ---
  1    1    3    5    2
  2    4    4    4    0
  3    5    3    1    1
  4    9    9    8    7
```

We use some formula to give each row a "rating" (or "score") based on the values of [PC1] through [PC4]. For simplicity, we'll use the average value. So we create a saved query in Access named [myRatings] ...

```sql
SELECT 
    myData.FID, 
    myData.PC1, 
    myData.PC2, 
    myData.PC3, 
    myData.PC4, 
    ([PC1]+[PC2]+[PC3]+[PC4])/4 AS Rating
FROM myData
```

... which returns ...

```
FID  PC1  PC2  PC3  PC4  Rating
---  ---  ---  ---  ---  ------
  1    1    3    5    2    2.75
  2    4    4    4    0       3
  3    5    3    1    1     2.5
  4    9    9    8    7    8.25
```

Now we can use that query as the basis for another query which finds the FID with the closest rating

```sql
SELECT 
    q1.FID,
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 q2.FID 
        FROM myRatings AS q2 
        WHERE q2.FID<>q1.FID 
        ORDER BY Abs(q2.Rating-q1.Rating), q2.FID
    ) AS Closest_FID
FROM myRatings AS q1
```

which returns

```
FID  Closest_FID
---  -----------
  1            2
  2            1
  3            1
  4            2
```

Notice that the ORDER BY clause of the subquery includes q2.FID as a "tie breaker". Without it the query would fail when it processed the row with FID=1 because both FID=2 and FID=3 have ratings that are 0.25 away from the rating for FID=1. In that case the subquery would return 2 rows despite the `TOP 1` clause. (It's an "Access thing".) Adding the second ORDER BY condition ensures that the subquery will always return just one row.

Comment: Thank you very match Gord for the nice code. All seems to be very nice formulated. However would it be possible to add a more complex similarity measurement (rating in your case) ? I was thinking something like a "per PC" difference (column difference) and then a summing of the individual PCs - as adding all PCs is a hard assumption for my data !

Comment: @user1396713 The rating for each row (FID) can be whatever formula you like. It could be a simple average (as above), a weighted average, or some other calculation that provides a single "score" for each row. Just change the `([PC1]+[PC2]+[PC3]+[PC4])/4` calculation to whatever you decide is appropriate.

Comment: Hello I am running the above code and I am getting an error "Synax error in FROM clause". I think there is a small mistake somewhere but not sure what exactly !

Comment: @user1396713 Please edit your question to show the query you are trying to use.

Comment: Done - all sql query os there !